# Email Subject contains webpage Title

Tags: php, html

I want to auto generate an email 'Subject' which contains the 'Title' of the webpage from where user is sending an email.

For Example :

If my webpages title is like this : About us

then email should contain "subject section as About us"

I'm new to PHP so I don't have any idea how to implement this in my code.

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have **any** code at the moment? How far did you go before asking for help? If you didn't do anything, we are not gonna just pop you with a block of code ...

Comment: How is your code structured among your pages?  How do you define the "title" if the email functionality happens when one page posts a form to another page and their titles are different?  Start by considering, logically, how you would know what the page's title is.  Once you've defined the logic then move on to the code which would produce that logic.

Answer (score 0):

Put the title in a variable, and refer to it in both the HTML and the PHP script that sends the email:

```
<?php 
$title = "About us";
?>
...
<head>
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
...
<?php
...
mail($addr, $title, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. If I'm sending a mail from single page it worked for me already but I don't want to specify the page's title as if there are number of pages so I need a statement that generates the subject of email same as the Title of the page